# Solve a Partial Differential Equation in Mathematica when DSolve does not work

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving the following pde in mathematica

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t, t] + 1/10*D[u[t, x], t] + 1/5*u[t, x] == D[u[t, x], x, x]
```

However, the `DSolve[]` function did not work well. I am wondering how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you even sure that your PDE has a closed-form solution?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. Haven't touched this kind of pde before.

Comment: If you just want something you can plot, use `NDSolve[]` instead.

Comment: Are you just looking for the general solution of this PDE, or trying to find a particular solution by "find the general solution first, then substitute it into the conditions to find the particular solution"? If the latter, are you looking for an analytic solution or a numerical solution? If the former, put your conditions together with the PDE into `DSolve`, if the latter,  put your conditions together with the PDE into `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 3):

This PDE does have a symbolic solution, and it can be obtained by expanding `u` in terms of exponentials to obtain a dispersion relation.

```
Factor[(Unevaluated[D[u[t, x], t, t] + 1/10*D[u[t, x], t] + 1/5*u[t, x] - 
  D[u[t, x], x, x]] /. u[t, x] -> u0 Exp[I {k x - w t}])][[-1, -1]]
(* -2 - 10 k^2 + I w + 10 w^2 *)
```

Solving the dispersion relation for  `k`, and substituting the result back into the exponentials yields

```
Flatten[ReplaceAll[u0 Exp[I {k x - w t}], #] & /@ Flatten[Solve[% == 0, k]]]
(* {E^(I (-t w - (Sqrt[-2 + I w + 10 w^2] x)/Sqrt[10])) u0, 
    E^(I (-t w + (Sqrt[-2 + I w + 10 w^2] x)/Sqrt[10])) u0} *)
```

The general solution is an arbitrary sum of such functions.

Answer (score 2):

As it evident from the comments that by now you should have solved the `pde` yourself. If no then see this?

Your `pde` is a second order linear one, so probably `DSolve` should give an analytical solution,

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t, t] + 1/10*D[u[t, x], t] + 1/5*u[t, x] == 
  D[u[t, x], x, x]
```

Now calling on `DSolve`

```
dsol = DSolve[pde, u, {t, x}]
```

No solution has been generated by `DSolve`. The next option is (as mentioned by @xzczd) to use the numerical solver `NDSolve`. For this you need to have two initial conditions and two boundary conditions. Here I have choose some random ones,

```
ics = {(D[u[t, x], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, u[0, x] == Sin[x]};

bcs = {u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 10] == 0};
```

Calling `NDSolve`,

```
sol = First@
  NDSolve[Join[{pde}, bcs, ics], u[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

You will see a warrning of inconsistent initial or boundary conditions, this is because I choose some random ones.

Finally, visualizing the output of `NDSolve`

```
Plot3D[u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {t, x, u}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]